# How to select row in FMDB?

Tags: ios, fmdb

Friends
I Used FMDB and it is working very well, but i tryed to select single row but it is gives me an error

this is code

```
FMResultSet *fResult= [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM contents WHERE id = 1"];
[fResult next];
NSLog(@"%@",[fResult stringForColumn:@"title"]);
```

Thank you

Comment: What data type is your id column?

Comment: it is text. i do not want to use while or  any loop, just i want to select only single row

Comment: You report that you received an error: What was that error message? We cannot help you if you don't tell us what the error was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your results. For example:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM contents WHERE id = 1"];

if (!rs) {
    NSLog(@"%s: executeQuery failed: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);
    return;
}

if ([rs next]) {
    NSString *title = [rs stringForColumn:@"title"];
    NSLog(@"title = %@", title);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%s: No record found", __FUNCTION__);
}

[rs close];
```

You are flying blind if you don't (a) check the `executeQuery` return code; and (b) if it failed, examine `lastErrorMessage` so you know why it didn't work.

Comment: Just wondering if all these have to be enclosed in `FMDatabaseQueue` for thread safety including operations like `insert` etc.,

Comment: Yes, if you're interacting with your database from multiple threads, then one would use `FMDatabaseQueue` to coordinate those various database requests. There's a lot more to writing thread-safe code than that, but that's beyond the scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this ?

```
NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:DBName ofType:@"sqlite"];
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];

if (![db open]) {
    return;
}

FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:databasePath];

[queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

    FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM TableName"];

    while ([results next]) {

        NSString *str = [results stringForColumn:@"your_column_name"];
    }
    [results close];
}];

[db close];
```

Comment: Thank you but i do not want While or any loop.  i want to only single row like: WHERE id  = 55;

Comment: if the results count is  even only one item, you can use above code.

Comment: @kakkuk If you don't want `while` loop, you can do `if ([results next]) {...}` and otherwise the code sample is the same. The key point, though, is that you always should check the result of your FMDB calls (e.g., don't just call `[results next]` without checking to see if it was successful).